How to check if the new window request is from pressing mouse wheel in Webview2
Normally web browser will open a new tab and switch to the new tab if you clicked on <a href="" target="_blank"> or execute open() in JavaScript. And if you click a link with mouse wheel browser will open a new tab but it won't switch the to the new tab.
The reason I need to know how the page was openned is because the way of open it will effect on what I bold in first paragraph
If you are not sure what I am talking about you can search something on Bing because Bing will open a new tab for the result's website instead of using current tab, try to click the result with LeftClick and mouse wheel you will see the difference. I want to do something like this on WinUI3 Webview2.
It seems like there is no this kind of EventArgs in Webview2.CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested event. I guess this can be done with JavaScript but I haven't found any solution for it. What can I do?

How to detect middle mouse button click?

Yes, that's my problem

Well, then inject the script when the DOM is loaded (AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync()) and take action depending on the [event].button state

I solved it with adding event listener of mouse button 1 down for every  tag in JS. Thank you

Try handling the NewWindowRequested event, get the target Uri and pass it to a WebView2 control in a new tab.
private void CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested(CoreWebView2 sender, CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    args.Handled = true;
    var targetUri = args.Uri;
    // Pass this targetUri to the WebView2 control in the new tab.
}

UPDATE
Let me show you a basic example for a TabView control with WebView2 controls. This will open a new tab when you click a link with the mouse middle button.
MainPage.xaml
<Page
    x:Class="WebView2Demo.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:WebView2Demo"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <TabView
        x:Name="WebView2TabView"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        TabItemsSource="{x:Bind TabViewItems}" />
</Page>

MainPage.xaml.cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace WebView2Demo;

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Uris.Add(DefaultUri);
        WebView2TabView.AddTabButtonClick += WebView2TabView_AddTabButtonClick;
        WebView2TabView.TabCloseRequested += WebView2TabView_TabCloseRequested;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Uri> Uris { get; } = [];

    public ObservableCollection<TabViewItem> TabViewItems { get; } = [];

    private Uri DefaultUri { get; } = new Uri("https://www.google.com/");

    private void WebView2TabView_AddTabButtonClick(TabView sender, object args)
    {
        AddNewTab(DefaultUri);
    }

    private void WebView2TabView_TabCloseRequested(TabView sender, TabViewTabCloseRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        RemoveTab(args.Tab);
    }

    private void AddNewTab(Uri uri)
    {
        var newWebView2 = new WebView2
        {
            Source = uri,
        };

        newWebView2.CoreWebView2Initialized += WebView2_CoreWebView2Initialized;

        var newTabViewItem = new TabViewItem
        {
            Header = "New Tab",
            Content = newWebView2,
        };

        TabViewItems.Add(newTabViewItem);
    }

    private void RemoveTab(TabViewItem tabViewItem)
    {
        if (tabViewItem.Content is WebView2 { CoreWebView2: { } coreWebView2 })
        {
            coreWebView2.DocumentTitleChanged -= CoreWebView2_DocumentTitleChanged;
            coreWebView2.NewWindowRequested -= CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested;
        }

        TabViewItems.Remove(tabViewItem);
    }

    private void WebView2_CoreWebView2Initialized(WebView2 sender, CoreWebView2InitializedEventArgs args)
    {
        sender.CoreWebView2.DocumentTitleChanged += CoreWebView2_DocumentTitleChanged;
        sender.CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested += CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested;

        // If you want to select the tab of the newly created WebView2, uncomment the following line.
        //WebView2TabView.SelectedItem = TabViewItems
        //    .FirstOrDefault(tabViewItem => (tabViewItem.Content as WebView2)?.CoreWebView2?.FrameId == sender.CoreWebView2?.FrameId);
    }

    private void CoreWebView2_DocumentTitleChanged(CoreWebView2 sender, object args)
    {
        if (TabViewItems
            .FirstOrDefault(tabViewItem => (tabViewItem.Content as WebView2)?.CoreWebView2?.FrameId == sender.FrameId) is { } targetTabViewItem)
        {
            targetTabViewItem.Header = sender.DocumentTitle;
        }
    }

    private void CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested(CoreWebView2 sender, CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        args.Handled = true;
        AddNewTab(new Uri(args.Uri));
    }
}


But the thing is I have to determine do I have to switch the tab for user or just open a new page in the background. Chromium and firefox can do something like this.

I updated my answer. I hope it helps ;)

Thank you, I found a way to solve it with javascript
